# How should I implement delayed topic architecture in python Kafka

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am. building a project which uses Kafka . I have to implement retry strategies, if a msg process failed in the main topic it will be published to retry_topic. Here I want to try /retry to send/consume a message after every 15 minutes. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Kafka consumer should process the message after 15 minutes corresponding to the timestamp in the msg data. I am using python Kafka client.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KlausD. Hi :) .I have tried to configure Kafka consumer with retry_backoff_ms and request_timeout_ms. Is it possible to configure Kafka in such a way that it will fetch uncommitted messages in a periodic time (15 minutes).